# Create Primitive and then Move it Right After

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a script that deletes a cube primitive and then creates a new sphere primitive. How would I then move that sphere primitive?

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.gameObject.tag != "Destroy") 
    {
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sphere;
    private bool spawnSphere = false;
    private GameObject sphereThatIWantToMove;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (spawnSphere)
        {
            sphereThatIWantToMove = Instantiate(sphere, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            spawnSphere = false;
        }

        //Code that moves the sphere
    }
}
```

In my code I added a public GameObject, so that I could load a sphere prefab to it.
Then you instantiate that prefab, but store the instance in another GameObject variable, then you can just use GameObject.Transform.Position to move it around.

Some more detail on actually moving the sphere:

```
    float x = sphereThatIWantToMove.transform.position.x;
    float y = sphereThatIWantToMove.transform.position.y;
    float z = sphereThatIWantToMove.transform.position.z;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        y--;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        x--;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        y++;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        x++;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.PageUp))
    {
        z--;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.PageDown))
    {
        z++;
    }

    sphereThatIWantToMove.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

The GameObject's coordinates are stored as a Vector3 in Transform.Position. You cannot edit that value directly, instead you have to break the values out (they're floats) using GameObject.Transform.Position.x, GameObject.Transform.Position.y, and GameObject.Transform.Position.z. Then you change those values and load them back in with a "new Vector3"

I hope that helps!